# How to make this javascript unobtrusive?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unobtrusive-javascript, google-visualization

I have this javascript code, from google charts api right in the bottom of my view :

```
<div id='visualization'></div>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
function drawVisualization() {
        // Create and populate the data table.

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<%=raw @pie_gender %>)

        // Create and draw the visualization.
        new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
            draw(data, {title:"Men and Women"});
      }
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
</script>
```

I've tried to put this js code in my assets folder under a .js file, and include it in my headers, as well as replacing `<%=raw @pie_gender %>` with `this.getAttribute('data-message')` and putting my div as ', but then i get a javascript error `"getAttribute" does not exist for object window`

I have also tried to pass my array as an input argument like : `onload="drawVisualization(<%=raw @pie_gender %>)`, but then I get "Error: Not an array"

What might I be doing wrong ?

**EDIT**

@pie_gender = [['Gender', 'Occurences']['M', 10]['F', 5]]

Based on example from [google](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#pie_chart)

**EDIT 2**
If i print the json output

```
<% logger.debug "Pie Gender : #{@pie_gender.to_json}" %>
        <div id="visualization" onload="drawVisualization(<%= @pie_gender.to_json %>)" > </div>
```

,it seems just fine :

```
Pie Gender : [["Gender","Receipts"],["",25000],["F",8658]]
```

but it seems that something happens while sending this as an argument to my js function, because it still says that message is not an array :

```
function drawVisualization(message) {
        // Create and populate the data table.
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(message);

        // Create and draw the visualization.
        new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
            draw(data, {title:"Men and Women"});
      }
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

Comment: If you're using Rails helpers in ANY view, the extension for your file has to be `.xxxx.erb`. But that doesn't seem to be your problem. Post full error please

Comment: whatever that @pie_gender is, it has to be output as syntactically valid Javascript, which means you need to JSON-encode it.

Comment: Hi @varatis, I put teh javascript into a js file under my assets folder. It's just like "application.js"

Comment: @MarcB `@pie_gender` is an array with format [[Gender Occurences][M 10][F 5]] ... How would putting this into json would solve the problem?

Comment: @itsalltime Post full stack error. Please. Also are you sure the javascript is getting included? Do a view source on your page

Comment: @itsalltime: because it doesn't matter how ruby turns that array into a string - you're inserting that string into a javascript code block, so ruby has to output valid javascript, which means you need to use JSON - (J)ava(S)cript (O)bject (N)otation - if it's json, it's valid javascript. `[[A B][C D]]` is not valid javascript.

Comment: @varatis, the error is a javascript error : `Uncaught Error: Not an array`, that basically comes out of google function.

Comment: @MarcB, when I write the code inline with my view, I don't need to convert it to json, I pass the array directly and it works just fine, showing the chart...does rails convert to json automatically?

Comment: @varatis, google javascript function catching the error looks like this : `m("google.visualization.arrayToDataTable",function(a,b){var c=new U,e,f,h;Zm(a)||d(n("Not an array"));`

Comment: I've just noticed i had some differences from google sample, and just edited my question accordingly. My problem now is passing from rails into the javascript function with an argument...What would be the best way to pass a vector like `[['Gender', 'Occurences']['M', 10]['F', 5]]`

Comment: I have added a new edit that i hope might clarify what i'm doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To workaround this, I inserted my javascript code in a partial

_googlescript.html.erb

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function drawVisualization() {
        // Create and populate the data table.

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<%=raw data_array %>)

        // Create and draw the visualization.
        new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
            draw(data, {title:"Men and Women"});
      }
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
</script>
```

in my view I rendered the partial in the bottom of the page, and removed the onload, which just seemed not to be doing a thing... :

```
<div id="visualization" > </div>
...
<%= render partial: 'shared/googlescript', locals: {data_array:@pie_gender} %>
```

Now i can see the chart again...but i still feel there is a better answer to my question.